# Windows 10 on 2019 model laptop running in ATA mode instead of AHCI

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers, ahci

I have a Lenovo V-Series Laptop [81HN V130-15IKB](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v130-15ikb/81hn). It is a 2019 model laptop and should support AHCI. However the information from HD Tune seems to indicate that it is using UDMA Mode 5:

[image: HD Tune Screenshot]

I think the hardware (motherboard and HDD) are not that old and that the software is supposed to show something like AHCI or UDMA Mode 6. Note that I never installed any drivers and let Windows Update manage the drivers:

[image: Intel AHCI Controller Driver in Device Manager]

So, is my HDD performing the way it should? I think the HDD is not using a feature called NCQ and I feel like it is thrashing so bad.

Comment: The driver description shows 6th gen which would be Skylake from 2015/16. Are you sure the model is from 2019 or is this just the date you bought this old notebook? BTW: the driver also says that it is the AHCI driver but as you only have an HDD Features like NCQ are not really relevant, that is more important for SSDs and servers.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly indicates Windows is SATA is in AHCI mode hence the reason you have a AHCI driver installed. I see no evidence that the mode is IDE instead of AHCI.  When you boot into UEFI what is the setting set to?

Comment: @robert so ncq applies to SSDs only? And the processor is 8th gen I am sure. That's what the stickers on the box say.

Comment: @ram there is no such option in bios. I don't see any mention of ide/data/ahci

Comment: @SalmanA Unless a laptop was manufactured <2012, the only choices in the BIOS/UEFI firmware for _SATA Operation_ would be ATA, AHCI, and RAID _(if motherboard has a RAID chip, such as Intel RST)_. It would be unusual for the UEFI firmware to not have an option for the SATA mode/operation, and since that model's HDD SATA ports are SATA III _([specs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lenovo+V130-15IKB+specs))_, the only way the HDD could be in ATA mode would be if ATA was manually selected in the UEFI firmware or if that drive is using the optical bay's SATA port, which is always SATA II.

Comment: @jw there is no option to choose the mode in bios, I checked all menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is some confusion : UDMA does not conflict with
AHCI. AHCI only conflicts with IDE or RAID.

[Ultra DMA (UDMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDMA)
is an evolved version of
[Direct memory access (DMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access).
Both are methods used for transferring data from main memory to a device
without passing it through the CPU. Without (U)DMA, the CPU would be
occupied for the duration of data transfer, with horrible consequences
for performance.

There is no conflict, and your device is likely functioning correctly.
[Native Command Queuing (NCQ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing)
is usually automatically enabled, if supported by the device.

Comment: HDD Tune lists OP's drive as ATA/ATAPI - SATA II. The [specs](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Lenovo/Lenovo_V130_15IKB/Lenovo_V130_15IKB_Spec.PDF) list the HDD's SATA ports as SATA III, so the only way it could be recognized as ATA SATA II would be if the SATA Operation Mode in the UEFI firmware is set to ATA instead of AHCI, or the HDD is using the optical bay's SATA port _(optical bay SATA ports are always SATA II)_